What does “Be it my loss” mean?
I found this cryptic line in Frost's poem called Now close the windows
My English teacher says that it originally comes from the phrase "Let it be my loss" but I wonder if there is any other interpretation.

See this question What is the meaning of be it used in the sentence below

@BillyKerr That answer doesn't fit this question.

The English teacher's comment is wrong and confused. It does not "come from that phrase"; and, the phrase mentioned by the teacher would not replace the phrase in the poem (which simply means "that would be my loss").

BE there is a survival of the subjunctive, which was used in a variety of situations, including phrases like "let it be", which is not a declaration of fact (declarative) but a statement of what you would be willing to accept as fact or would wish to have the fact be.
In the poem there is an ellipsis of "Let".  Close the windows to shut out the sounds of the fields, and if there is any bird singing out in the fields, let the ensuing silence be my loss.
P.S. If the syntax of that sentence in the poem were completely different, the conditional meaning of BE (if, whether) would be possible: "Be it my loss or not, I want the windows closed". But for that meaning, "Be it my loss" must be the protasis of the conditional sentence; in the poem, however, "be it my loss" is the apodosis of the conditional:

... and if there is [a bird singing], protasis
Be it my loss. apodosis

P.P.S. I should say that ellipsis was just an easy way to explain the presence of a subjunctive context, since there is a nearby sentence with let.  But the BE form can move to front position, followed by the subject, here a "dummy" subject, it [standing in for "there is a bird singing"], followed by the predicated complement  (my loss). That is just a valid variant syntax for this sort of concessive something-I'm-willing-to-accept-as-reality verbal construction.  Compare the fossilized construction "Be that as it may".

I think your explanation really makes sense. Why does "Let it be my loss" turn into "Be it my loss" when you omit "Let"?

Please see the P.P.S.

I don't think this is a college student.

I finally got it. Thank you for your help

Would it be reasonable to think of this as an imperative like in 'be good'?

@j4nd3r53n  No one is being given a direct command. It's more like we are being let into the speaker's thoughts on the situation, and for that reason are being asked to accept what the speaker is willing to accept:  if there is a bird singing now, so that with the windows closed I would not hear it, consider it my loss.

@TimR  Does the explanation that the subjunctive survives in the "BE" form indicate a sentence like "It's essential that he be here"?

Yes, "it is essential" does license a clause where the verb is in BE form. It's essential, critical, necessary, of utmost importance, etc.  The licensed clause is not a declaration of an existing reality but of a needed reality.

He may or may not be here at the time of that utterance.  "Can't we tell him to leave? -- No, it is essential that he be here.".   or "Where is he? It is essential that he be here!"  So it's not counter-factual but a-factual or meta-factual.

There’s something not right about the first paragraph here. The subjunctive may have been used in phrases whose meaning is like ‘let it be’ (roughly equivalent to a third-person imperative), but never in phrases whose structure is like ‘let it be’ (imperative + infinitive) – those have always had plain imperatives, because the subject of let is the listener. I’m also iffy about calling it any kind of ellipsis: one is not derived from the other by any process like elision, they’re simply two completely different ways of expressing the same thing.

@JanusBahsJacquet  I think of it as a jussive subjunctive.  I addressed the ellipsis issue in my P.P.S.

@TimR I found the subjunctive mood to be a very interesting part of English.

"Be it" is a somewhat archaic conditional meaning "whether it be". It can also be used on conjunction with another conditional (such as the if clause in this poem) to mean "it will be" or "let it be". By 'somewhat archaic' I mean that you are unlikely to hear it in everyday speech, but it is found in poetry and extremely formal language.

Now close the windows and hush all the fields;
If the trees must, let them silently toss;
No bird is singing now, and if there is,
Be it my loss.

Frost is saying that he understands closing the window will mean he can't hear the birds singing - but he is prepared to accept that "loss" because, in that moment, he wants the quiet.

I think that here it is an ellipsis of "let".  Let it be my loss.

And we have Be it ever so humble, there’s no place like home, which  could be paraphrased as No matter how humble (one’s) home is, there’s no place else that’s like it (to one).

Similarly, the phrase ‘be that as it may’ (which I think is becoming a stock phrase, as the grammatical form fades).

Now Close the Windows
by
Robert Frost
1874 –
1963
Now close the windows and hush all the fields;
If the trees must, let them silently toss;
No bird is singing now, and if there is,
Be it my loss.
Be it my loss is an old form (archaic) for saying: even if it is my loss.
If the windows are closed, the person cannot hear anything going on outdoors: in the fields, in the trees, the trees themselves or birds. He cannot hear the birds singing because of the closed windows. Since he has told someone to close the windows, he's saying close the window even if it is my loss; the loss of hearing all those things from nature.
Be + it [rest of sentence] can mean "even if", and except for poetry has gone out of modern usage.
You might occasionally hear it in expressions like: Be that true or false, they might not believe you.

You know what I would possibly think that the best "translation" is a plain "then it's my loss" rather than "even if it's my loss".

@Fattie Be they rich or poor, they are all human beings. For me, it's even.

Right, good one !
